# How do I stub a method of an instance only if a specific instance variable has a value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, stub, ruby-mocha

I have an object `MyObject`:

```
class MyObject

  def initialize(options = {})
    @stat_to_load = options[:stat_to_load] || 'test'
  end

  def results
   []
  end
end
```

I want to stub the `results` method only if `stat_to_load = "times"`. How can I do that?  I tried:

```
MyObject.any_instance.stubs(:initialize).with({
  :stat_to_load => "times"
}).stubs(:results).returns(["klala"])
```

but it does not work. Any idea?

Comment: I can see a mismatch on `result` versus `results` in the question. Probably not your answer, but worth fixing?

Comment: Oups, copy/paste error

Comment: I don't even know if this is possible, but probably the right solution is to inject the object or the class, then you have a lot more control over it. Difficult to say / give examples without seeing how this code is being used.

Comment: How do you code it if you have my class MyObject. I want to stubs for rails tests.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think there is probably a simpler way to test what you're trying to test, but without more context I don't know what to recommend. However, here is some proof-of-concept code to show that what you want to do can be done:

```
describe "test" do
  class TestClass
    attr_accessor :opts
    def initialize(opts={})
      @opts = opts
    end

    def bar
      []
    end
  end
  let!(:stubbed) do
    TestClass.new(args).tap{|obj| obj.stub(:bar).and_return("bar")}
  end
  let!(:unstubbed) { TestClass.new(args) }

  before :each do
    TestClass.stub(:new) do |args|
      case args
      when { :foo => "foo" }
        stubbed
      else
        unstubbed
      end
    end
  end

  subject { TestClass.new(args) }

  context "special arguments" do
    let(:args) { { :foo => "foo" } }
    its(:bar) { should eq "bar" }
    its(:opts) { should eq({ :foo => "foo" }) }
  end

  context "no special arguments" do
    let(:args) { { :baz => "baz" } }
    its(:bar) { should eq [] }
    its(:opts) { should eq({ :baz => "baz" }) }
  end

end
```

---

```
test
  special arguments
    bar
      should == bar
    opts
      should == {:foo=>"foo"}
  no special arguments
    bar
      should == []
    opts
      should == {:baz=>"baz"}

Finished in 0.01117 seconds
4 examples, 0 failures
```

However I'm making a lot of use of special subject/let context blocks here. See http://benscheirman.com/2011/05/dry-up-your-rspec-files-with-subject-let-blocks/ for more on that subject.

Comment: This answer is for RSpec not mocha

Answer (score 0):

Try out below, this should work as expected:

Here, Basically we are actually stubbing `new instance` getting created and also stubbing `results` method of the instance which is getting returned.

```
options = {:stat_to_load =>  "times"}
MyObject.stubs(:new).with(options)
                    .returns(MyObject.new(options).stubs(:results).return(["klala"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use plain old Ruby inside your test to achieve this.

```
MyObject.class_eval do
  alias_method :original_results, :results
  define_method(:results?) do
    if stats_to_load == "times"
      ["klala"]
    else
      original_results
    end
  end
end
```